# Set default value for a field in share point 2010 list

Tags: list, sharepoint-2010, default-value

I have a lookup field in list in share point 2010, how to set a default value for that field at inserting operation

Comment: It's not possible out-of-the-box so you are going to need some custom code.  Are you looking for a JavaScript-based solution when the user opens the form, a custom event receiver when the user is saving the form, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript, override the PreSaveAction method and push whatever you like into the lookup column. this happens just prior to the post to the web server, so you cna do all validation and checks.

Beware though, the value you insert must exist in the lookup list or the post will fail, ie don't push a value of "abc" if "abc" is not on the list of possible options fo rhte lookup column.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preselect some value in lookup control (dropdown) when dialog is open you need to do it by JS. You need to hook onload (JS) event of the page. There are some libraries that makes it easier to set SharePoint field values e.g. [SPJS-utility](http://spjsblog.com/2013/08/20/spjs-utility-js-v1-17/). Common way is that you send id of item using URL parameter and get by JS and then set it to field. Speaking of lookup beware of the fact that SP renders lookup control in different way in IE for less than 20 items and for more than 20 item.